# how to take the mean of each cell from three different data frame?

Tags: r

now I am exampling a matrix but should be the same as a data frame 
imagine we have three data frame

```
Mat1<- matrix(rexp(3, rate=.1), ncol=3, nrow=5)
Mat2<- matrix(rexp(3, rate=.1), ncol=3, nrow=5)
Mat3<- matrix(rexp(3, rate=.1), ncol=3, nrow=5)
```

I know if I want to plus each and all cells and make one data frame out of it, 
I can simply do

```
M <- Mat1+Mat2+Mat3
```

but instead I want to take the mean of each three cells and not the plus of each three cells, how can I do that ?

Comment: If those are matrices (as they should be for numeric data): `M <- (Mat1+Mat2+Mat3)/3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many matrices, you could use `Reduce` after placing the matrices in a list.  Get the `+` of the elements and divide it by the length of the list.

```
lst <- mget(paste0('Mat', 1:3))
Reduce(`+`, lst)/length(lst)
```

Same way, you can do

```
Reduce(`+`, lst)
```

In general, if the object names follow a specific pattern, this would be useful.  But, if the matrices are `xy13542xy', 'z62', 'Ak912f', etc, without much pattern, then we need to construct the list manually

```
lst <- list(xy13542xy, z62, Ak912f)
```

Suppose, if there is a pattern i.e. `s1, m1, d1` etc

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern='^[a-z]+\\d+'))
```

Comment: can you please make it in a way that if the names are different, does not effect on the results?

Comment: @Nemo Suppose your matrices are `m1, n2, s1` etc, `Reduce('+', list(m1, n2, s1))/3`  It depends upon whether there is any pattern in the object names. If there is you can also do `mget(ls(pattern='[A-Za-z]+\\d+'))` to get it into a list.

Comment: thanks, maybe you can add these info into your answer, for those who might use this latter

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can just do this:

```
(Mat1+Mat2+Mat3)/3
```